# How do i get user country Name using facebook api connect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook application. I have to know the country of the logged in user using the graph API.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the user table through FQL.
The column you are looking for is current_location.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

You can use FQL through the graph api:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY
```

Comment: sorry for this question but where i will write this query link ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, during [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) you *might* need to request the `user_location` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). I don't know if this is required to get information from the logged in user. Try.

After you have the required permission (if needed), make a request to the Graph API using this URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN`.

You can try to use the link Facebook provides in their documentation. Make sure you're signed in to your Facebook account in the current browser, and [click here](https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=2227470867%7C2.AQDgJa5BGKwEFAJK.3600.1308567600.0-578251212%7Cevt4Vtqw024sVBGK7t19-7tFZno) to see your own information.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the profile data to a MySQL table you can do something like this to extract the name of the country:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( users_facebook.hometown,  ',' , -1 ) ,
    hometown,
    ABS( LENGTH( REPLACE( hometown,  ",",  "" ) ) - LENGTH( hometown ) ) AS num_commas
FROM
    users_facebook
WHERE
    ABS( LENGTH( REPLACE( hometown,  ",",  "" ) ) - LENGTH( hometown ) ) <> 0
```

Something similar should be possible in PHP (split, last element...) when you're acquiring the data.