# Fetch country name of facebook user via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to fetch the facebook users country name via the Graph API . ? I have already taken permission and fetch the other relevant information.

The post here [How do i get user country Name using facebook api connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409201/how-do-i-get-user-country-name-using-facebook-api-connect) talks about FPL .

Can i do it via Graph or is there any other way of manipulation possible to infer the users country . ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i am able to do it ! Posting here for others .

```
                $facebook_location = $facebook_profile['location'];
                $facebook_city_country = $facebook_location['name'];
                $city_country=explode(',',$facebook_city_country);
                $city=$city_country[0];
                $country=$city_country[1];
```

You may refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ for the detailed documentation on how to use the location api .

Comment: This works ONLY for non US/Canadian countries. Living in Milano, Texas doesn't tell me that it's in the US. :-/